# Animation with CGPoint in for loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, cgpoint

I'm trying to do an animation where when a person clicks from point A to Point B  on screen the object should slowly slide straight across (horizontally) from point A to Point B. 
I'm new at animations by the way.

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:10
                              delay:0
                            options:nil
                         animations:^ {

                             if(magnifier != nil){
                                 [magnifier removeFromSuperview];

                             }

                             magnifier = [[MagnifierView alloc] init];

                             magnifier.viewToMagnify = imageView;
                             magnifier.touchPoint = newPoint;
                             [imageView addSubview:magnifier];
                             [magnifier setNeedsDisplay];                             
                         } 
                         completion:nil];
```

but for some reason it is moving it way up and then eventually to point B. sort of in a weird curve.

how can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a loop. Just use the animation block that you have.

- Before the block, set the object to point A.
- In the block, set it to point B. The block will cause it to animate.
- Also, initialize your object outside the animation block.

Example:

```
// initialize your object outside the block
magnifier = [[MagnifierView alloc] init];
[magnifier setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]; // for example, start at 0, 0 (width and height set to 100 for demo purposes)
[imageView addSubview:magnifier];

[UIView animateWithDuration:10
 delay:0
 options:nil 
 animations:^ {

    // inside the animation block, put the location you want the magnifier to move to
    [magnifier setFrame:CGRectMake(500, 0, 100, 100)]; // for example, move to 500, 0

} 
completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    // do anything you need after here

}];
```

Also for options you can set `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` if you want an easing effect at the beginning and end of the animation or `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` if you want an equally timed animation with no easing (there are others available, look up UIViewAnimationOptions).

Comment: will that still move it slowly straight across?

Comment: Yes, this code would move it diagonally from the top left corner (0, 0) to the bottom right at (500, 500) in a straight line

Comment: i meant straight across from point A  to point B. not diagonally.

Comment: Just change the coordinates in the code to move it however you need. "Straight across" doesn't tell me what movement you're trying to make, so I made sample code using (0, 0) and (500, 500) as an example. If you want to move from (0, 0) 500 pixels to the right, for instance, use (0, 0) and (0, 500).

Comment: By the way, this is in UIKit coordinates, so the top-left corner is (0, 0) and as he numbers increase you're going down and right.

Comment: yes. I want to move straight across like : (0,50) to (2, 50) to (3, 50) to (4, 50) etc.

Comment: Don't think of the animation as a series of steps. Instead, think of it as one motion, with (a) a start point, (b) an end point, and (c) a duration. In my code above, change (0, 0, 100, 100) to be the (start x, start y, width, and height) of the object before the animation and change the (500, 0, 100, 100) to be the (end x, end y, width, and height) of the object after the animation. To control the speed of the animation, alter the number `animateWithDuration:10` to a different number of seconds than 10.

Comment: Note: I just updated the code to move to the right and not diagonally to help you understand this motion.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I think I now see what you are talking about.